# Program breaking suddenly in if statement

Tags: c, pointers

So I'm doing this assignment. My job is to make two functions, `char* readLine()` which is supposed to read one line from standard input, and return pointer to that string.

Other function is `char** readLines(int *n)` which is supposed to read couple of strings (separated by new line) from standard input and return an array of char pointers, where every pointer points to one of the strings inputted. Also, the function is supposed to return number of strings read by pointer `int *n`. Process is repeated until empty string (actually pressing enter only) is inputted.

This is how I did it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
#define WRD 20

char* readLine() {
    char *p, *first; // declaring pointers
    p = (char*)malloc(WRD*sizeof(char)); // WRD stands for maximum word length
    if (p == NULL) exit(1);
    first = p; // remebering the position of first char in string

    // put every char in string, stop when you hit enter. next line is overwriting new line with string escape.
    while ((*p++ = getchar()) != '\n');
    *--p = '\0';

    // return start position of string
    return first;
}

char** readLines(int *n) {
    char** p;
    char* temp;
    p = malloc(MAX*sizeof(char*)); // allocate space for array of char pointers
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        temp = readLine(); // keep readLine() pointer in temporary variable
        printf("%p\n", temp);
        if (*temp == '\0') // check if it's empty string, if yes break the loop
            break;
        else
            *(p+i) = temp; // if it's not empty, write it in the array of char pointers
        i++; // increment counter by one
    }
    printf("break"); //this doesn't even get executed at all

    *n = i; // dereference pointer with number of inputted words
    return p; //return an array of char pointers
}

int main() {
    int *n;
    char **p;
    p = readLines(n);
    printf("success");
    printf("%d", *n);
}
```

The weird thing is that if I just copy paste `char** readLines()` block into `int main()`, everything is fine. I get "break" as output, which never happens by the implementation that I provided. Code exits at `if (*temp == '\0')` line, when empty string is provided, only program output is "Command terminated".

Why this block of code acts differently while in function and in main()? Thanks in advance, sorry but I'm very new at c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `n` in `readLines` isn't updating the one in `main`, since you're passing it by value (and worse, it's not pointing anywhere in particular). You have a layer of `*` indirection that you shouldn't in `main`. Change it to this:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    char **p;
    p = readLines(&n);
    printf("success");
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

As for not getting `break`, that's because your mistake with `n` triggered Undefined Behavior, which means literally anything is allowed to happen, including [traveling back in time to before you made the mistake, and undoing the `printf` that already ran](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it. I was wondering if I'm passing some value inappropriately, but I reckoned because `n` wasn't called up until the end it couldn't be important in that while loop. Thank you very much, + for that article.